# @ManyToMany initiating LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, lazy-evaluation

For the some testing purposes, I'm trying to have JUnit test throwing LazyInitializationException.

My case is that I have 3 entities

```
@Entity(name = "Role")
public class Role {
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<AppUser> appUsers;
    ...

}

@Entity(name = "Group")
public class Group {
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groups", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<AppUser> appUsers;
    ...
}

@Entity(name = "AppUser")
public class AppUser {
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    @ManyToMany(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "APPUSER_ROLE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
    ...

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    @ManyToMany(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "APPUSER_GROUP", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
    private Set<Group> groups;
    ...

}
```

I generate some test data, where all these 3 are correctly persisted in DB with the relation. I commit the transaction then.

But then I try in the same test method to read `Role` (based on id), but I get also all the other related entities read (seem to be loaded eagerly). Why is it so? How can I come to `LazyInitializationException`?

**EDIT**: OK I'm not interested in the general description, rather I'd need a code sample, as I can't have it initiated in my case. General description doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in the fact that even if I commited transaction within my test method, I had to close the EntityManager as well and reopen it again to trigger `LazyInitializationException` in my setup.

Finally I ended up with the following entities code:

```
@Entity(name = "Role")
public class Role {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<AppUser> appUsers;
    ...

}

@Entity(name = "Group")
public class Group {
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(name = "GROUP_APPUSER", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
    private Set<AppUser> appUsers;
    ...
}

@Entity(name = "AppUser")
public class AppUser {
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(name = "APPUSER_ROLE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
    ...

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "appUsers")
    private Set<Group> groups;
    ...

}
```

So rather than:

```
Group <- AppUser -> Role
```

I had:

```
Group -> AppUser -> Role
```

Even tough it was not necessary, because already on the 1.st lazy load (`Group -> AppUser`) lazy problem occured.

And the test code itself, the most important part was:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(group);
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();

// reinit em
...

// load group from DB and afterwards close em
em.close();
...
// following throws LazyInitializationException :)
group.getAppUsers().iterator().next();
```

Answer (score 3):

> How can I come to LazyInitializationException?

When you have:

1. an entity member which is lazy loaded (such as a OneToMany or a ManyToMany)
2. there is no active transaction (entity is detached)
3. the member is not loaded yet
4. you try to access the entity member, which should trigger a lazy load but it is not possible because the entity is detached

Comment: thanks for answer, but even if I try to do em.detach(role) loaded from DB, still it already contains the AppUser reffering to Role. So it seems all is loaded eagerly, even if I'd expect it beeing lazy loaded. I feel like there is a problem in my mapping (annotations).